# Does git checkout update the staging area?

Tags: git

The staging area can be updated via `git reset`, is there any case `git checkout` (or with many extra parameters) would update the staging area from new HEAD?

**UPDATE**: It seems git's behavior depends on whether you check out a file or a branch/commit.

1. If no file specified, it **updates HEAD** to point/switch to given branch/commit, and will warn and block the switch if there is any change in staged area and work tree. For example, `git checkout DevBranch`.
2. If file is specified but no branch/commit, it copies the specified file from staged area to work tree and doesn't touch stage area (**doesn't update HEAD**). For example, `git checkout file.txt` or `git checkout -- file.txt`.
3. If both branch/commit and file are specified, it updates the specified file in both stage area and work tree from given branch/commit (**doesn't update HEAD**). For example, `git checkout DevBranch -- file.txt`.

Comment: explain what you mean by "updated" in "Staged area can be updated via git reset"

Comment: @Urbane I mean changing the content in staged area after the command (`git checkout`) is done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you specify a branch or commit to `git checkout`, the staging area is indeed updated as well as the working directory. So, for example:

```
git checkout head~1 myfile.txt
```

will take the version of myfile.txt that is in head's parent and copy it to both the staging area *and* the working directory. If you do not specify a commit or branch, i.e.:

```
git checkout myfile.txt
```

then the contents of myfile.txt will be copied *from* the staging area to the working directory; the staging area itself is not changed.

Comment: Does it still apply if there is no file name specified in the command line?

Comment: @Thomson - Yes; in fact, that is the most common use of `git checkout`. When that happens, you switch HEAD to point to another branch or commit, and the entire staging area is changed to match that branch/commit. Note that is you do not specify a file name, and you have made local changes to a file that would be changed by `git checkout`, the operation will fail, so you do not lose any changes. This protection is not there when you _do_ specify a file name.

Comment: Stupid question: does the documentation specify that checkout stages files? The docs say: "It updates the named paths in the working tree from the index file or from a named <tree-ish>" and doesn't really say much else.

Comment: If you look under the "Description" section at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout for `git checkout <branch>`, it says: "To prepare for working on <branch>, switch to it by **updating the index** and the files in the working tree, and by pointing HEAD at the branch." (emphasis mine).